# Connector make and type

Tags: identification, connector

Does anyone know what exactly this connector is? I've been looking at the MOLEX Pico-SPOX series as well as JST-ZH, but none of them seem to exactly match. The board manufacturer is not available to tell me. The pins are spaced 1.5mm apart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The pins are spaced 1.5mm apart.

I believe that the pitch is actually 2 mm.

I used my [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2&s=WR-WTB%20620&fl=0000000000000000000000002000000000-8-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) to identify it.

[image: Wurth 620105131822]

{Digikey}

Made by:

- [Adam Tech 2SH-C-05-TR-SMT](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adam-tech/2SH-C-05-TR-SMT/9833030)
- [EDAC 140-505-417-060](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/edac-inc/140-505-417-060/13544237)
- [JST SM05B-PASS-TBT(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SM05B-PASS-TBT-LF-SN/2773428)
- [Sullins SWR201-NRTN-S05-HM-BG](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sullins-connector-solutions/SWR201-NRTN-S05-HM-BG/2769628)
- [Wurth WR-WTB 620](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/620105131822/2508483)